# How can I install Windows Server 2008 on Windows Vista using VMware?

Tags: vmware, windows-server-2008, windows-vista

Can I install Windows Server 2008 on Windows Vista using VMware?

I would like to know where I can find the VMware software and details on the steps to install Windows Server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use VMware to install pretty much any OS including Windows Server 2008... all you need to do is click File -> New -> Virtual Machine... and then follow the wizard. If you need to know how to install Windows Server 2008 itself then you should probably not be using it in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You can install Windows Server inside of a virtual machine running on your computer, but it won't be the same as if it were running directly on your computer (not in a virtual machine).

You will first need a license for Windows Server. You can buy those from various online retailers, or obtain one for free if you are a high school or university student through Microsoft's [DreamSpark](https://www.dreamspark.com/default.aspx) program.

Next, you will need to download virtual machine software. There are several options out there; VMware and VirtualBox are the most popular.

- [VMware Server](http://www.vmware.com/products/server/overview.html) (free)
- [VMware Workstation](http://www.vmware.com/products/workstation/) (paid)
- [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) (free & open source)

Determine which will work best for you depending on what you need to do. For basic features, all of them should work equally well. The installation process will be different for each one; check the manual for whichever you choose to use. VMware has a guided install option, where it will set up the guest operating system for you if you provide the installation disk. With VirtualBox you just install the OS yourself as you would on a normal computer by booting of the DVD within the VM.

- [VMware Server Manuals](http://www.vmware.com/support/pubs/server_pubs.html) (download the manual and go to the section on "creating an updating virtual machines)
- [VirtualBox Manual](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/UserManual.html) - [configuring virtual machines](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html)

Comment: You can also just use an evaluation version of Windows Server 2008.

Comment: @taspeotis true, but that'll only last 30 days.